# Best primitive several-minute daily routine for time-restricted people?

Tags: weight-loss, workout-routines, workout, workout-types, routine

I do every day 10 push-ups, and with that ends my daily routing.

I also do a massive 2 hours walk that includes climbing and walking for a long distance.

I would like to improve my daily routine, but I don't want to depend on external gear, because   in my experience it doesn't last long.

I want to give each day a few minutes, and I prefer to do the most important and profitable exercises at that time. I know you'll will shout that I'm a lazy person, and that might even be true, but currently I want to help myself under these circumstances, and I think it's better little than nothing.

Oops, forgot to mention, I'm 27 yo.

So I'm begging for some recommendation on what that should be.

Comment: Best? What are you looking to gain out of this? It depends on what you want.

Comment: Health, weight-loss, over-all body-strength, but the real thing is health

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've offered very little clarification apart from a desire for better "health". I would strongly rethink your aversion to using any equipment, as there are certain movements that will be hard to replicate with your body weight alone. But, lets assume you buy nothing.

**The laziest possible option for good health is the turkish getup**

Grab the nearest heavy thing you can - a bag filled with heavy things is fine - hold one of the straps, and perform 5-10 [Turkish getups](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Kettlebell/KBTurkishGetup.html) per side per day.

[image]

Why? ["Your ability to stand up unaided after sitting on the floor could be an indicator of your mortality"](http://www.medindia.net/news/ability-to-stand-up-after-sitting-on-floor-may-influence-mortality-111474-1.htm#ixzz2WjwQ3qA6). Adding some getups will work your legs, hip flexors, abs, lower back, shoulders and help with your proprioperception. This coupled with your long walks cover your basic movement needs and cardiovascular requirements.

It may seem like an odd movement, but the ability to static hold an object, while getting up from the floor, balancing between your legs is much tougher than you think.

You can also look into bodyweight fitness, but even that requires straps or pullup bars sometimes. Beyond that, if you want more specific advice, you need to figure out some specific goals.

Comment: WOW! I'm impressed. I didn't expect such a great answer. You just justified my question :)

Comment: "Any heavy item" is great. I'll use bottles of water, could be found always and everywhere. The statement in my question meant to avoid heavy non-portable equipment, that used to ruin my practice consistency.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://news.health.com/2013/06/05/a-10-minute-hiit-workout-you-can-do-anywhere) is a 10 minute [HIIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-intensity_interval_training) workout.

What you need for this workout is your sneakers, a stopwatch, a bench or chair, and a little bit of space, and perform each exercise at a high intensity for 45 seconds followed by 15 seconds of rest. Keeping up the intensity is key to this workout, so make sure you’re really pushing yourself during those 45 seconds. But, of course, work at your own pace and rest as needed.

[image]

You can see demonstrations of the individual exercises [here](http://news.health.com/2012/03/06/at-home-workouts/).

Comment: The link you provided may expire and become useless in the future.  It would be better if you provide a **complete** answer that references the link.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to the Turkish getup (excellent answer), I would say 3-5 [yoga sun salutations A](http://www.google.se/imgres?imgurl=http://www.poweryogaottawa.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Yoga-Sun-Salutation-Warmups-V2.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.poweryogaottawa.com/sun-salutation-a-b-practice-sheets-free-download/&h=3300&w=2550&sz=1495&tbnid=lCYeWO-KKDVMwM%3a&tbnh=90&tbnw=70&zoom=1&usg=__2dFILFURGs5EXWRy0R8Pax-R97w=&docid=Wy2r2xqAU5C45M&sa=X&ei=_-7CUeSeI-eC4ATs0oGQAQ&ved=0CDoQ9QEwAw&dur=482). No equipment at all and will activate the posterior chain. Great as a morning routine.